# Rails/Capybara: How to make attach_file work with active storage direct upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rails-activestorage

I am having trouble to attach files to inputs which use direct upload inside my system tests (Capybara). All tests worked before I switched to direct upload. I have also tried to manually submit appropriate forms via Browser and everything works there. Unfortunately, no luck with Capybara :/.

Inside view, I have following input:

```rb
<%= f.input :desktop_files, as: :file, input_html: { direct_upload: true, multiple: true } %>
```

and file is attached to input in system test by:

```rb
attach_file 'uploads_create_assets_former[desktop_files][]', "#{fixture_path}/files/image.jpg"
```

When I try to run test which uses similar piece of code, I get:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Error reading image.jpg}
  (Session info: headless chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

and when I check console inside browser opened by Capabyra, I can see following error:
[FileReader error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58IvX.png)

My suspicion is that Capabyra/Selenium has problem to access attached file, but I don't know about any other way how to assign file to input. Maybe there is some Capybara magic which comes to play here :) -- hopefully, I am not only one who uses Rails direct upload and needs to test this piece of code with system tests...

I am using:

```
ruby (3.0.0)
rails (6.1.4.1)
selenium-webdriver (4.0.3)
capybara (3.35.3)
webdrivers (4.7.0)
```

and for capybara:

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[headless disable-gpu no-sandbox window-size=1440x768]
  )
  options.add_preference(:download, prompt_for_download: false,
                                    default_directory: Rails.root.join('tmp/downloads').to_s)
  options.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, capabilities: options)
end
```

**Edit:**

Html code of form which should do upload looks like this:

```html
<form class="formtastic uploads_create_assets_former" id="new_uploads_create_assets_former" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/upload/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
      <li class="file input optional" id="uploads_create_assets_former_desktop_files_input"><label for="uploads_create_assets_former_desktop_files" class="label">Dateien (Computer)</label>
        <input id="uploads_create_assets_former_desktop_files" multiple="multiple" data-direct-upload-url="http://127.0.0.1:49538/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" type="file" name="uploads_create_assets_former[desktop_files][]" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>  
  <fieldset class="actions">
    <ol>
      <li class="action input_action " id="uploads_create_assets_former_submit_action">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Nächster Schritt" data-disable-with="Nächster Schritt" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have not deviated in any way from Active Storage direct upload documented at https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads. Upload of files starts on former submission.

**Another edit:**

I have prepared minimalistic Rails app where you can try to play with my issue: https://github.com/martintomas/capybara-direct-upload. I have double checked that path is correct (otherwise Capybara::FileNotFound is raised), tried relative and absolute paths. I have also checked that anybody can read file:

```sh
-rw-r--r--  1 martintomas  staff    26436 Oct 22 12:51 image.jpg
```

Same problem happens when tests are run on my local machine or inside CI environment. To be honest, I have run out of ideas so I have decided to go for **hacky solution** now.

**Hacky solution:**

If you absolute trust active storage direct upload implementation and you don't have extra js code related to direct upload, you can turn it off inside system tests.

```rb
def attach_file(locator = nil, paths, make_visible: nil, **options)
  turn_off_direct_upload # Capybara does not work with direct upload
  super
end

def turn_off_direct_upload
  page.execute_script 'document.querySelectorAll("input[data-direct-upload-url]:not([data-direct-upload-url=\"\"])").forEach((input) => { delete input.dataset.directUploadUrl } )'
end
```

Comment: Please show relevant portion of the actual HTML of the page rather than the erb template, and describe the user behavior which triggers the file upload.

Comment: It looks like you may have a permission issue with the file you’re trying to attach. Try making sure the permissions allow everyone to read the file. Another thing to try is specifying the full filename with an absolute path

Comment: is this `"#{fixture_path}/files/image.jpg"` generating the correct path?